# How to initialize a custom chromecast app from android chrome

Tags: google-cast, mobile-chrome

I'm trying to develop a custom chromecast app for my web application,
I've registered the app and my chromecast device and it works fine with my desktop chrome (cast extension installed).

But it doesn't start the chromecast app from my android chrome (40.0.2215.109).
I've looked at google's developer guide for chromecast, but I can't find how to implement the initialization process for mobile chrome.

Where might I find the documentation for that?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing. I have a custom receiver app that works on desktop, however the default chrome app is launched on Chrome for Android. It seems that custom receiver are not yet supported on this plateforme. Did you find anything?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Cast SDK is not supported on mobile chrome.

Comment: but ive seen it done on youtube, if i open watch a video it shows the cast icon and it opens up the youtube app on my chromecast.

Comment: As I said, Cast SDK is not supported on mobile chrome, meaning that you as a developer cannot use the Cast SDK to provide such experience for your own app.

Comment: So youtube is some kind of exception? Well that's too bad, but thanks for your reply!  is the a plan to support the SDK for android chrome in the future?

Comment: @AliNaddaf is Cast SDK supported on mobile chrome now? I didn't find any information about mobile chrome support in cast developer documentation